# Awkward behaviour when outputting an array backwards

Tags: c++11

in a recent assignment i have to output a array backwards.
The size of the array is "n". This is the working code:

```
for(size_t i=n; i-- > 0;){
   f(values[i]);
   ++rc;
}
```

When i try to use this code:

```
for(size_t i=n-1; i >= 0; --i){
   f(values[i]);
   ++rc;
}
```

The second code allways produces random values, most likely because it refers to uninitialized memory i guess. But shouldn't this do the same, because i tried some example code with a simple
char-Array and with this it worked. f() is a function which we have to use.
Does anybody have a clue why this could happen?

Comment: "The second code allways produces random values" contradicts "i tried some example code with a simple char-Array and with this it worked"

Comment: the first code i posted is the code in my project for the assignment, the funny thing is if i use the 2nd code it doesn't work in my project but it works in my small simple test program.

Comment: There seems to be a parenthesis missing in the second code. Should it not be `f(values[i])`?

Comment: The second code won't compile, because there is a closing parenthesis missing. Are there any other differences between the code you posted and the code you tested?

Comment: Sorry the paranthesis is not missing in the example code, i just made a mistake. The other difference was that in my example code i used "int".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting undefined behavior.

```
for(size_t i=n-1; i >= 0; --i){
   f(values[i]);
   ++rc;
}
```

`size_t` is an unsigned type so `i >= 0` will always be true. Once you get to 0 and try to decrement it, it'll wrap around and you'll get the max value for `size_t`. And you most likely are accessing invalid memory afterwards with an infinite loop (or a crash due to the invalid memory access).

Comment: Ok, that explains a lot. I thought "int" and "size_t" would behave the same way.

Comment: It's an [unsigned type that can store the maximum size of an object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) and most likely bigger than an int, I understand the confusion though.